# Postfix attempting all delivery virtually

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

We have Postfix configured for virtual domains and virtual mailboxes and it's running quite nicely.  However, Postfix now thinks that everything except my_destination should be delivered virtually.  And this is a problem because it means we can't use virtual aliases to deliver external mail.

Whenever I try sending an email through this server to a domain which we are not responsible for (ie. does not appear in the mysql table of virtual domains and is not in my_destination) then we get the following error message:

> 554 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table

And this happens for every single domain we do not host, regardless of what the domain name is.  When I send email to an existing user at a domain listed in my_destination then it delivers locally ok.

How do we tell Postfix to not attempt virtual delivery for domains that it is not responsible for?  How do I get it to deliver that email to the correct external host (presuming of course the sender has permission to relay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague resolved this in the early hours of this morning. He discovered that it was our SQL query for checking whether a domain was virtual or not.  We'd incorrectly assumed that it should return a list of virtual domains with `select distinct domain` when in fact it actually wanted to check if a domain was virtual or not with `select domain where domain = %s`

We were switching from the old style configuration for MySQL lookups to the new one, and had made an incorrect assumption based on the fact that a text file would return a list of domains and so why shouldn't MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

can you paste the contents of your main.cf removing any private info?

I can only assume that your transport_maps has gone a bit crazy